# On Zero sum perfect matching

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-complete, matching, clique, subset-sum

Fix $c\geq1$.

Input is a $m$ vertex complete graph with edges assigned $a_1,\dots,a_{\frac{m(m-1)}2}\in\Bbb Z$ in some order.

Is it $\mathsf{NP}$-complete to decide if there is a perfect matching of zero-sum for cases:

**(A)** $|a_i|\leq m^{\frac1c}$

**(B)** $|a_i|\leq\log^{c}m$?

I looked at the literature for perfect matching and subset sum and could not find this version.

The closest was minimum weight perfect matching which has a polynomial time algorithm as in http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~bico/papers/match_ijoc.pdf which however in this case does not work.

It also seems like restricted version of subset sum and so the complexity is not obvious because of size of $|a_i|$.

---

**Update: Including case C.**

**(C)** What if $a_i$ needs roughly $m^\alpha$ bits for some fixed $\alpha>0$?

Comment: I must be missing something. Given that you allow real values, can't any unbounded instance be trivially re-scaled to satisfy your bounds? This would make them irrelevant for the question.

Comment: @KlausDraeger The point is input precision cannot exceed certain implicit requirements because of input length. I can make this explicit in problem.

Comment: @KlausDraeger I made it $\Bbb Z$ which suffices for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in RP in both **(A)** and **(B)** by a variation of [Lovasz's algorithm](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221150072_On_determinants_matchings_and_random_algorithms):

Fix a finite field $F$ of characteristic $2$ on at least $q=4m\max_i |a_i|$ elements.
Consider the graph's [Tutte matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_matrix) $T(r)$ where you replace indeterminate $x_{ij}$ by $y_{ij}r^{a_{ij}+q/4}$, where $y_{ij}=y_{ji}$ is a uniformly and independently randomly chosen element in $F$ and $r$ is an indeterminate. Now observe that the determinant equals $\sum_{\mbox{Matching }M} \prod_{ij\in M} y_{ij}^2r^{2a_{ij}}$.

Hence, you can solve for the coefficient of $r^{q/2}$ in the polynomial $\operatorname{det} T(r)$ to see if there is a zero-sum matching. Compute the determinants of the numerical matrices $T_r$ obtained after replacing $r=1,2,\ldots, q$ in $T(r)$, and use interpolation to recover the coefficient. It is non-zero with probability at least $1-m/q$ if and only if the graph had a zero-sum matching.

**Update:** In **(C)** the problem is NP-complete.

Consider an instance $b_1,b_2,\ldots, b_n$ and $t$ to Subset Sum, i.e. is there a subset $I\subseteq [n]$ such that $\sum_{i\in I} b_i=t$?
We can embed this in a Zero-sum matching problem as follows. Consider the bipartite graph with biadjacency matrix $\begin{bmatrix}I_n & I_n & 0\\I_n & I_n & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, where $I_n$ is a $n\times n$ identity matrix, and weights $\begin{bmatrix}B & 0_n & 0\\0_n & 0_n & 0\\ 0& 0 & -t \end{bmatrix}$
where $0_n$ is a $n\times n$ all-zero matrix and $B=\operatorname{diag}(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)$ is a $n\times n$ diagonal matrix.
Now observe that there is a zero-sum perfect matching if and only if there is a solution to the Subset Sum instance.

Comment: Is problem $\mathsf{NP}$-complete if $|a_i|\approx2^m$? The problem seems still in $\mathsf{NP}$ right (input size is $m$ bits per edge for $\frac{m(m-1)}2$ edges)?

Comment: Yes it is, there is a pretty straightforward reduction from subset sum.

Comment: I do not see it could you please include?

Comment: Here is (almost) a written up reduction for what you want: Look at the Equal Weight Matching hardness reduction in http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2722174. Then embed it as a zero weight matching problem.

Comment: @AndreasBjörklund what if only subset $I$ has $|I|=2\ll n$ which means bipartite graph has a perfect matching of size $n$ while subset sum has subset of size $2$ that sums to $t$?

Comment: @Turbo I don't understand your comment, the subset sum may very well consist of only two terms?

Comment: The question was based on a complete graph. Is your answer also valid for general graphs or does the solution only work for complete graphs? I know this question 5 years old :/